# App has errors. "Unexpected token ." Trying to add a delete button

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

I've been following a guide by [George Mcknight](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9i3CCy3NpYM)
for creating a database app with Meteor JS.

I've got everything working, but now I want to add a delete button to delete entries.
To do this, I followed a comment in the video on how to add it.

But I stumble upon an error "Unexpected token ."

Inside "(Meteor.isClient)" I've entered

```
Template.main.events({
    'click .remove': function(){
        Todl.remove({this._id});
    }
});
```

And the html/template:

```
{{#each todl}}
    <tr>
        <td>{{make}}</td>
        <td>{{model}}</td>
        <td>{{brand}}</td>
        <td><button type="button" class="remove btn-danger">X</button></td>
    </tr>
{{/each}}
```

I can't see why why the "." in "Todl.remove" would crash it?

Answer (score 0):

Well that was easy.

Tried to diagnose why it failed, and found out it worked if I dropped the "{}".

In other words, change:

```
Template.main.events({
    'click .remove': function(){
        Todl.remove({this._id});
    }
});
```

To this:

```
Template.main.events({
    'click .remove': function(){
        Todl.remove(this._id);
    }
});
```

Comment: Because `{}` are used to define key => value pairs object which means something like `{id: this._id}` is expected by JS instead of `{this._id}`